# Rewriting decay algo such that values don't have to be recalculated

Tags: algorithm

I'm keeping count of popular posts on a high traffic website based on voting and vote age. Specifically, vote weightage decays to half (50%) after the passage of a day.

Meaning a post with 100 votes today is more popular than a post with 150 votes from before. A post with 250 votes from before, however, will trump the fresh post with 100 votes.

To accomplish this, I multiply aggregate post scores by 97.15% every 60 minutes, using cron. Is there any way to model this algorithm such that I don't have to use a cron job at all?

---

reddit's ranking algorithm [doesn't](https://medium.com/hacking-and-gonzo/how-reddit-ranking-algorithms-work-ef111e33d0d9#.5bt2q28i9) require cron, whereas hacker news' [does](https://medium.com/hacking-and-gonzo/how-hacker-news-ranking-algorithm-works-1d9b0cf2c08d#.iwe330hwj). Of course they're different algos, but reddit's algo ensures newer stories simply get a *higher score* instead of re-calculating scores for old posts like HN.

That's the essence I'm trying to capture when formulating an algorithm for my scenario as well. Maybe I could arbitrarily fix some point in the future. Weights of votes would increase as this date is approached. But problem with that approach is it won't scale beyond the future date, and if the date it too far in the future, there will simply be float overflow today. Ergo, this has to be done precisely.

I'm finding it hard to come up with something here. Can someone help in formulating this? An illustrative example would be great!

p.s. if it helps, I'm using python2.7

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're averse to using cron here?

Comment: A better algo cleanly erases the need to re-evaluate old posts

Comment: How are the rankings stored? Are they in a database? What kinds of queries are you supporting? Do you ever need to do something like look at all posts ever, or just recent ones?

Comment: Currently they're in the DB, but I'm going to introduce redis to the mix. The average user looks at popular posts, although some highly engaged ones go much, much deeper. An elegant algo here is possible, thus looking to create one.